# Kafka Topic not getting flushed when Spark consumer reads from it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using the following consumer code in Spark to read from a Kafka Topic:

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
  .option("subscribe", topicName)
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

The code reads from the Topic as expected, but the contents of the Topic are not getting flushed out as a result of this read. Repeated execution results in the same set of messages getting returned over and over again.

What should I do to cause the messages to be removed form the Topic upon read?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't remove topic messages when consumed

Your Spark code is part of a Kafka *consumer group*, and it would need to acknowledge that a message has been read, and *commit those offsets*, which I believe Spark does on its own, periodically, by default, but you can disable this with setting the option of `enable.auto.commit` to `false`, which is highly recommended because you will want to control if Spark has succesfully processed a collection of records.

[Checkpointing](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/) or commiting offsets to a durable store are [some ways](https://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/05/07/spark-kafka-achieving-zero-data-loss.html) to preserve your offsets in the event of a restart / failure of a task, and not re-read the same data

Answer (score 0):

As [crikcet_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) mentioned Kafka does not remove logs after consumption. You can manage log retention within Kafka using either size based policy or time based settings.

`log.retention.bytes` - The maximum size of the log before deleting it

`log.retention.hours` - The number of hours to keep a log file before deleting it

`log.retention.minutes` - The number of minutes to keep a log file

`log.retention.ms` - The number of milliseconds to keep a log file

You can read more about these parameters [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs)

On top of that additional mechanism to handle the log retention is log compaction. By setting following parameters you can manage the log compaction

```
log.cleanup.policy

log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms
```

You can read more about that [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_compactionconfig)